# Graph theory tree rank sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

let $T=(V,E)$ be a tree with $n$ vertices , which his degree sequence is $d_1 \le d_2 \le ... \le d_n$ if and only if $d_1\gt 0$ and $d_1+d_2+...+d_n=2(n-1)$
$$$$
i managed to prove it one direction with indaction... but for days im not able to prove its a tree...(in the other direction).
Please help me or guide me how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you've proven that if $T$ is tree than $d_1\gt 0$ and $d_1+d_2+...+d_n=2(n-1)$.

Lets move in the other direction. We will prove that if $d_1 >0$ than the graph is connected. We will prove that by induction. The case of $n = 2$ is obvious. Suppose we've proven that for $n = k$. Check the case of $n = k + 1$. If it's not connected then we have connected components of smaller size $\{C_k\}, k = 1, 2,\dots, m$. Each component is connected and therefore have at least $|C_k| - 1$ edges. Then the sum $d_1+d_2+...+d_n = 2(n-1) - 2(m - 1) < 2(n-1)$. We see that $m = 1$ and graph is connected. It remains to see that connected graph with $n$ vertices has at least  $n-1$ edges, being exactly $n-1$ edges only for trees.

Comment: Im not really sure if i understood you allright... 
$C_k$ is a circle compoment?(C is a circle after all) , and if so how is it that we have |C_k| -1$ edges?
@Macaronnos

Comment: @user152711, $C_k$ is k-th connected component. Connected subgraph of $T$

Comment: @Marcronnos ok but if so why the sum is 2(n-1)-(m-1)?

Comment: @user152711, oh, I missed 2. It should be 2(n-1)-2(m-1). Explanation is as follows. We know for every $k$ that the number of edges in the component $C_k$ is at least $|C_k|-1$ - one less than the number of vertices in the component. Lets sum the edges for all components. We get at least: $\sum_{i=1}^m(|C_k| - 1) = \sum_{i=1}^m(|C_k|) - m = n - m$.  But the sum of degrees is twice bigger than the number of edges. So, we get 2(n-1)-2(m-1).

Comment: Well sum is twice then the number of edges $sum=2|E|=2(n-m)=2n-2m$
what am i missing? or you just did $2n-2m=2n-2m-2+2=2(n-1)-2(n-1)$?

Comment: @user152711, $2n - 2m = 2(n-1) - 2(m-1)$ :)

Comment: hahaha just what i wrote... well thank you very much :)